# Efficient way to get media MIME type

Tags: go, mime-types

I have a media URL and I want to get mimetype for that media file. What is an efficient way to do it in Go?

I tried mimetype library in golang

```
 mtype := mimetype.Detect(body)
```

but it's taking almost 500 ms. How to do better than this?

Comment: Can you not read the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: "but it's taking almost 500 ms" this is likely dominated by the time to read the network request. There's little you can do to optimize that from a programmatic standpoint.

Comment: Actually, I need media support of many different mimetypes like audio/aac, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint which I can't verify with content type.

Comment: Why can't you read that from Content-Type?  Is the server broken?

Comment: It gives content type as "application/octet-stream" which is not useful for me.

Comment: So the server is effectively broken. Do you have any control over the server? Can you elaborate on what you're doing?  As worded, the direct answer to your question appears to be "there is no better way". But there's a lot of context missing.

Comment: if the server supports range request you could ask for a first ~1kb of data - that should be enough to detect the mime type but might be a bit faster than downloading whole file...

Comment: Does server support Range requests?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid download content if you want to raise performance.

1. Try to use HEAD method to create request to get only headers (server should support it), in some cases `Content-Type` will be informal
2. Check `Content-Disposition` HEADER - may be it has `application/octet-stream`  in `Content-Type` but  `myfile.aac` in it - so you can detekt mime type by name in some cases - and some cases will be covered, by file extension
3. Check that server supports Range query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests - in this case you have an option not to read whole file, but just part of it - most binary formats has special byte-mask that define it's content type - may be `mimetype` package not covered it but you can write your on in this case - it's not so much work

So you strategy is:

1. make HEAD query - if Content-Length and/or Content-Disposition header contains required info - OK
2. make range request just for first N bytes and check format markers

If server not supports Ranges and HEADER -
do GET query, but do not read whole content - fetch just Headers and N first bytes from stream.